# Choosing the minimum among different pandas rows that is not equal to zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
year   country apple orange peach banana pear export
2010   China    11    45     0      13    22   25
2011   China    6     5      26     33     2   44
2012   China    34    3      56     23     0   22
2013   China    22    45      2      2    27   14
```

I know how to get minimum value for each year such as:

```
df["min_f"] = df[['apple', 'orange', 'peach', 'banana' ,'pear']].min(axis=1)
```

How I can get the minumum non-zero values?

P.S: I don't wanna use the following trick as creates headache later on:

```
df = df.replace(0, np.NaN)
```

Comment: You now have enough reputation to vote!  Congratulations.  Feel free to show your gratitude by up voting answers that you found to be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
icol = ['year', 'country']
f = lambda x: x != 0
mins = df.set_index(icol).stack().compress(f).groupby(level=[0, 1]).min()
df.join(mins.rename('min_f'), on=icol)

   year country  apple  orange  peach  banana  pear  export  min_f
0  2010   China     11      45      0      13    22      25     11
1  2011   China      6       5     26      33     2      44      2
2  2012   China     34       3     56      23     0      22      3
3  2013   China     22      45      2       2    27      14      2
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution:

```
df.groupby(['year', 'country']).apply(lambda x: x[x > 0].min(axis=1))
```

Returns:

```
year  country   
2010  China    0    11.0
2011  China    1     2.0
2012  China    2     3.0
2013  China    3     2.0
dtype: float64
```

This should ignore non-numeric columns using pandas 0.19.2.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so we select the columns, get non-zero values and find min

```
(df[df[['apple', 'orange', 'peach', 'banana' ,'pear']] != 0]).min(axis = 1)
```

You get

```
    year    apple   orange  peach   banana  pear    min_f
0   2010    11      45      0       13      22      11.0
1   2011    6       5       26      33      2       2.0
2   2012    34      3       56      23      0       3.0
3   2013    22      45      2       2       27      2.0
```

Comment: I don't need to write the column names?

Comment: Not if you need min value across the entire row

Comment: Yeah but I have some string values, in different columns

Comment: I just didn't use them in the example

Comment: If you have other numeric columns that you are not using for finding the min, you will have to specify the columns. Strings won't be affected. See the edit

Comment: Exactly, I have also other numeric values

Comment: Yes, strings are excluded from the operation but if you want to pass a subset of numeric columns you can use `df[cols][lambda x: x!=0].min(axis=1)`  (this will require pandas 18 or higher).

Comment: @ Dogukan Yılmaz, here you go